# Can I implement instance count monitoring using TVirtualMethodInterceptor?

Tags: delphi, memory-management

[Virtual method interception](http://blog.barrkel.com/2010/09/virtual-method-interception.html) - introduced with Delphi XE - can be used to 'proxify' methods so that custom code can be executed before and after the original method.

Could this also be used to keep a count of all object instances in a Delphi application, by proxyfying the virtual methods TObject.AfterConstruction and TObject.BeforeDestruction?

If yes, this could be a simple way to analyse FastMM4 memory allocation statistics at run time (using the InstanceSize property of objects and matching it against the allocated memory blocks).

---

Update: sorry for asking a question which was very easy to answer from the DocWiki information - I have read the linked article first and only skimmed the example code

Comment: ...yes?  I can't see why not.  Did you try it?  Implement the proxies, increment and decrement a counter (possibly using [thread safe increments/decrements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683614(v=vs.85).aspx)) and, um... there you go.

Comment: Couldn't you do this much more easily by modifying FastMM sources?

Comment: @WarrenP FastMM has no knowledge of the actual types which it provides memory blocks for, it only processes memory allocation/deallocation requests

Comment: Although you can't use that particular class, there are still other ways. You could post a new question to ask more generally: How can I keep track of the number of instances there are of a certain class?

Comment: FastMM knows the values for Self pointers as they are allocated. If you could somehow hook the low level System interface that invokes FastMM to store the type information somewhere in a global in FastMM, then FastMM could pick up the context somehow. Anyways, I bet on RTL Code Hooking more than TVirtualMethodInterceptor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, that's not going to work. From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/RTTI.TVirtualMethodInterceptor), with my emphasis:

> Permits the user to dynamically intercept virtual method calls on **specified instances** of a particular class type.

The problem is that you need to get hold of each and every instance before you can proxify. But you are hoping to proxify in order to get hold of instances. So you are now caught in a chicken and egg scenario.